# Are Ether gas fees higher than Cardano fees?

Tags: gas, gas-price, fees, altcoin

When trading ETH for altcoins on decentralized exchanges, fees right now can be around $60-150$ per trade.

A tutorial on Cardano (ADA) smart contracts shows that they will have zero fees (for smart contracts). not too sure about Cardano-altcoin trades, but ADA-ETH trades seems to resemble ETH gas fees but I might be wrong.

Is it a truth that Cardano fees are lower than ETH fees?

Answer (score 2):

Ether gas fees are subjected to change based on the network usage, a simple ETH transfer based on the current gas price is about 0.0021 ETH which corresponds to 3$.

So these prices are high simply because the network usage is also high, having zero fees has the issue that you are subject to anyone spamming the network since there is no fee.

At the moment cardano fees are simply lower than ethereum ones because

1. Cardano has much lower network usage
2. It might be able to handle more tps than ethereum